# Integrate 3rd-party sdk to Android apk

Tags: android, ads

Is it possible to integrate 3rd-party ad sdk to android application if I have only apk, and don't have source code project?
I know that it's possible to add jar lib to the project, but how to implement call of this library methods?

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't call the library itself. You call the **api**(custom classes) provided by the library for use. Example:

**android-support-v4.jar**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


 public class AvengerFragment extends Fragment {...
```

We use use the custom class Fragment provided by the lib